# Sending a https request in ahk that ignores untrusted SSL certificate

Tags: autohotkey

```
URL := "https 127.0.0.1: " . portLink

req := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.Open("GET", URL, False)
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " . authEncoded)
req.Send()
```

[Ahk error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVNk7.jpg)

The following code is working in python (requests lib included)

```
r = requests.get(url="https 127.0.0.1: " + portLink,
                     headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authEncoded, "Accept": "application/json"},
                     verify=False)
```

In python, the untrusted SSL certificate is ignored by adding `verify = False`

Comment: A Google search seems to tell me how to ignore SSL errors with WinHttpRequest. See [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/196243-winhttpwinhttprequest51-certificate-error/) for example. A Google search also shows more in depth options which you can specify, so maybe give that a try if that doesn't work.

Comment: @0x464e That fixed my issue, thanks

Comment: You should delete this question or 0x464e could make an answer and you could accept it.